# Javascript Data Structure Question (Stack)

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, stack

I am learning data structures/algos with javascript, and I can't figure out a bug in my stack.  The code is:

```js
//first javascript algo

console.log("program working");

function Stack() {
  this.dataStore = [];
  this.top = 0;
  this.push = push;
  this.pop = pop;
  this.peak = peak;

  function push(element) {
    this.datastore[this.top++] = element;
  }

  function pop(element) {
    return this.datastore[--this.top];
  }

  function peak() {
    return this.datastore[this.top - 1];
  }
}

var FirstStack = new Stack();
FirstStack.push(1);
FirstStack.push(2);
FirstStack.push(3);

console.log("Peak:" + FirstStack.peak());
console.log("Pop:" + FirstStack.pop());
console.log("Pop:" + FirstStack.pop());
```

The error I am getting is

```
" this.datastore[this.top++] = element;
                               ^

TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined
    at Stack.push (/Users/mg8686./Desktop/javascriptalgos/algo1.js:13:32)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mg8686./Desktop/javascriptalgos/algo1.js:26:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
```

Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong?  Thanks!!

Comment: You have a typo: `this.dataStore` vs `this.datastore`.

Comment: Thanks RobG.  It's not letting me accept answers for another 8 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with the casing.

You have defined:

```
this.dataStore = [];
```

And trying to access

```
 this.datastore
```

Javascript is case-sensitive.